# Possible to hookup windows phone 7 with google contacts?

Tags: google

I am wondering can I setup my windows phone 7(nokia lumia 800) with [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/)?

Comment: You should see this link.. This will help you out!
http://blog.rushabhgosar.com/?p=981

Answer (score 6):

It's simply a case of going to: Settings -> email + accounts, and then adding a Google account.

You can then choose to synchronise Email, Contacts and Calendar (or any combination)

Comment: Hmm that does not seem to take the groups I created though. It seems to only take the contacts.

Comment: Groups don't sync (See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1569/106)

Comment: Yep that was my post as I was wondering if "live" groups sync let along google contact groups sync. I do find that pretty lame that their own "live' groups don't sync. Guess I will go ahead with my project of trying to make a google contacts app.

Comment: Yeah. I'm using google contacts with WP7, working fine, actually better than live contacts.

Answer (score 1):

As posted in this [link](http://blog.rushabhgosar.com/?p=981) there is an application on the market called 'gsync' that can actually do the needful. Just search on the Windows Phone store, its compatible on WP7 as well as WP8..