# How can I make a Windows Phone interface with the Google cloud?

Tags: 8.0, google

I'm looking at (finally) upgrading to a smartphone this year, and Windows Phone is currently at the forefront of my consideration. However, I'm concerned about how well it may integrate with the cloud-based services I use via Google. I know Microsoft has their own comparable cloud-based services, but I'm not interested in migrating any time soon.

The services I want to connect to my phone are:

- GMail
- Google Calendar
- Google Drive/Docs
- Google+
- Google Talk

How well does an out-of-the-box Windows Phone 8 OS integrate with these Google services? Are there apps available to work with those not natively supported by the OS? Are there any which I will just not be able to use with a Windows phone?

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1560/106 (For Gmail, calendar & contacts)

Answer (score 4):

- **GMail*** works out of the box.
- **Google Calendar*** works out of the box.
- **Google Contacts*** work out of the box.
- **Google Drive/Docs**  you can access a limited mobile version via your browser. [Some apps/methods](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-google-docs-your-windows-phone) provide various levels of support.
- **Google+** no official app and you can only use it via your browser.
- **Google Talk** no official app, but there are some in the [store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/search?q=google%20talk).

*Google is [ending Google Sync](http://www.zdnet.com/microsofts-windows-phone-to-add-support-for-google-sync-protocols-7000010575/) support for **new free** accounts starting July 31st 2013.

Comment: Thanks for the information and links. It would also be important to note that, per articles you've linked (or articles linked from those), Microsoft currently has no plans to add CalDAV or CarDAV support to replace the functionality currently provided by Google Sync.

Comment: Drive is most problematic..  have only been able to view, no editing (at least with spreadsheets) in my experience

Comment: @Iszi that might just be for Windows RT, a post on the same day says that they are adding it to Windows Phone http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/01/30/synching-google-services-with-windows-phone.aspx . Still enough time to wait and see what happens--if you start using it now you can use it forever: "If you've already connected your Google account to your PC using the Mail, People, or Calendar apps, this change doesn’t affect you at all. Your email, calendar, and contacts will continue to sync properly"