# App to access Google drive?

Tags: apps, 7.8

I am a Lumia 710 user. I wonder if there is an official or unofficial app to access google drive on WP 7.8. I am looking for something similar to the OneDrive app.

Comment: Surely this should be closed as off topic as per the FAQ: "Can you suggest an app that does X?"

Comment: @ClaraOnager those questions are off-topic, but wanting to using Google's services on Windows Phone is important for a lot of people. In saying that, this question is possibly a duplicate of http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/how-can-i-make-a-windows-phone-interface-with-the-google-cloud

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a Windows Phone interface with the Google cloud?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/how-can-i-make-a-windows-phone-interface-with-the-google-cloud)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google pretty much only has one official app and it is for search. However, doing a quick search I found the following third party apps. As I don't use Google Drive, I can't easily evaluate how they perform. I hope one of these are what you are looking for.

- [Gdrive WP7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/gdrive-wp7/9wzdncrcwm43)
- [GDocs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/gdocs/9wzdncrcwmvg)

Comment: I think there are some apps for access dropbpbox and google drive for windows phone. One of them is Gdrive, it's not from google. I've found several apps like this on www.mobileappsfor.net. There is a post about it.