# Do Groups Sync to Live Account?

Tags: windows-live, people

I made some groups in the people hub of my windows phone 7. I am wondering, do they sync up to my live account?

I checked the people hub and it seems like all my contacts are there but I don't see them in the groups I created.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, only groups created with Windows Phone 8 will sync via live/Outlook.com.

Comment: Though outside the scope of this question, it is also worth noting that groups will not sync with Google Contacts - I created a lot of contacts & groups on my Google Contacts and the contacts synced but the groups did not.