# How to import Android contacts to Windows Phone 7.8 via VCF file?

Tags: contacts, 7.8

I exported all of my contacts from my Android device to a VCF file but I don't see how I can import this on my Windows Phone 7.8 device.

The file is 251KB but appears empty in notepad and GMail doesn't accept the file.  Is there a place where I can import this on my phone to transfer all of my contacts?

Comment: Does Gmail give an error? Do you still have your Android Phone and is your current phone a Nokia? http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/possible-to-hookup-windows-phone-7-with-google-contacts Are your contacts synced to your Gmail?

Comment: If it appears empty in notepad there is something wrong with you export procedure. VCF files are simple text files, they are perfectly viewable on notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the vcf file is damaged.There was an error in the export.All of my contacts are lost!   Advice : Check your export before it is late ...