# Google Apps for Business with Windows phone?

Tags: contacts, google

I'm thinking about switching to WP8 from Android and evaluating what I need in order to live with it.

I have business account with google apps. Use contacts, email and calendar.

I found this:
[Possible to hookup windows phone 7 with google contacts?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/possible-to-hookup-windows-phone-7-with-google-contacts/1570#1570)

But I'm not sure if it's only with free accounts or it will work with business account as well?

Comment: I'm almost certain it will work. My Google apps accounts have always integrated nicely with features designed for Google accounts. iOS, Android, etc.

Comment: Business accounts you mean Google Apps (using you domain with Google services)?

Comment: Yes, paid account with my domain name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any email account will work with the WP8 email client, regardless of using IMAP, Exchange, POP3. Gmail accounts can use both IMAP and POP3, for the free email as well as for business accounts.

So no worries as I am in the same situation and all email accounts work on my HTC 8S.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use my google contacts, calendar, and email with my Windows 8 Phone, although I switched my primary accounts to my Microsoft ones.